# org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:No property a found for type -Spring

Tags: java, spring

**Controller**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<Object> login(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, @RequestParam("usser") String user, @RequestParam("password") double password) {
    Object response;

    List product = repository.findByA_usuarioAndA_contrasena(user,password);
    HttpStatus httpStatus;

    if (product != null) {
        response = product;
        httpStatus = HttpStatus.OK;
     //   httpServletRequest.getSession().setAttribute("user_session", repository);
    } else {
        httpStatus = HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED;
        response ="error";
    }

   return new ResponseEntity<>(response, httpStatus);
}
```

**Repository**

```
public interface Repository extends JpaRepository<Products, Long> {
        List  findByA_usuarioAndA_contrasena(@Param("usser") String user, @Param("password") Double password);


 }
```

**modelo**

```
package com.mifel.sam.model;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;

@Entity
@Table(name = "USUARIO", schema = "public")
public class Products implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -3009157732242241606L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int c_usuario;

    @Column(name = "a_nombre")
    private String a_nombre;

    @Column(name = "a_paterno")
    private String a_paterno;

    @Column(name = "a_materno")
    private String a_materno;

    @Column(name = "a_rfc")
    private String a_rfc;

    @Column(name = "a_usuario")
    private String a_usuario;

    @Column(name = "a_contrasena")
    private String a_contrasena;

    @Column(name = "c_status_id")
    private int c_status_id;

    @Column(name = "c_info_contacto_id")
    private int c_info_contacto_id;

    @Column(name = "d_registro")
    private Date d_registro;

    @Column(name = "c_usuario_id")
    private int c_usuario_id;

    @Column(name = "d_modifica")
    private Date d_modifica;

    @Column(name = "c_usuario_id_mod")
    private int c_usuario_id_mod;

    @Column(name = "c_usuario_mifel")
    private int c_usuario_mifel;

    public Products() {

    }

    public Products(String a_usuario, String a_contrasena){
        this.a_usuario =a_usuario;
        this.a_contrasena = a_contrasena;

    }
}
```

**Error**

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'indexController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'repository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'repository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property a found for type Products!
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:588) ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88) ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:366) ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1264) ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553) ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:761) ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867) ~[spring-context-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543) ~[spring-context-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.5.7.RELEASE.jar:1.5.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693) [spring-boot-1.5.7.RELEASE.jar:1.5.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360) [spring-boot-1.5.7.RELEASE.jar:1.5.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303) [spring-boot-1.5.7.RELEASE.jar:1.5.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118) [spring-boot-1.5.7.RELEASE.jar:1.5.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107) [spring-boot-1.5.7.RELEASE.jar:1.5.7.RELEASE]
    at com.mifel.sam.SAM.main(SAM.java:16) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'repository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property a found for type Products!
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1628) ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555) ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:208) ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1138) ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1066) ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:585) ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    ... 19 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property a found for type Products!
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.<init>(PropertyPath.java:77) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:329) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:309) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.from(PropertyPath.java:272) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.from(PropertyPath.java:243) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.Part.<init>(Part.java:76) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$OrPart.<init>(PartTree.java:247) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$Predicate.buildTree(PartTree.java:398) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$Predicate.<init>(PartTree.java:378) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree.<init>(PartTree.java:89) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.PartTreeJpaQuery.<init>(PartTreeJpaQuery.java:64) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:103) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateIfNotFoundQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:214) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$AbstractQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:77) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.<init>(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:436) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:221) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.initAndReturn(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:277) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:263) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java:101) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1687) ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1624) ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    ... 29 common frames omitted
```

Este error me sale al ejecutar el login

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Es porque estás utilizando "snake_case" para nombrar las propidades de Product. Te recomiendo que uses "camelCase".

Comment: gracias, asi fui como lo resolvi